# assignment from incompatible pointer type warning problem

Tags: c, pointers, struct

i keep on getting "assignment from incompatible pointer type" warnings and i can't find a solution!

```
MACHINE* create_machine(RESEAU *r){ // Creation d'une machine and erreur
MACHINE *m = malloc(sizeof(MACHINE));
if(m == NULL){
    printf("\nErreur");
    return NULL;
    }

ADRESSIP *ip = malloc(sizeof(ADRESSIP));
if(ip == NULL){
    printf("\nErreur");
    return NULL;
    }
```

and when i do this get the warning here!!

```
 m->suivant = NULL;
 m->ip=ip; //erreur
```

---

From Comments:

MACHINE is

```
typedef struct machine{ // la structure Machine ,, represente un pc 
   struct machine *suivant; 
   const char* nom; 
   struct ADRESSIP *ip; 
}MACHINE;
```

ADRESSIP is

```
typedef struct adressIP{ // la structure AdressIP 
    int n1; 
    int n2;
    int n3;
    int n4; 
 }ADRESSIP;
```

RESEAU is

```
typedef struct reseau{ // la structure reseau comme une liste 
    MACHINE *suivant; 
    long long size; 
    short vide; 
}RESEAU;
```

Comment: And we are supposed to know what `MACHINE` is?

Comment: What are the typedef of MACHINE, RESEAU, ADRESSIP? What's the line, between that you indicate ,that issued the warning?

Comment: What is the type of `m.ip`? If it's not `ADRESSIP *` ...

Comment: I suggest you to insert the type declarations into your question so we can best read the SW.

Comment: @SirJoBlack   MACHINE is

`typedef struct machine{ // la structure Machine ,, represente un pc
    struct machine *suivant;
    const char* nom;
    struct ADRESSIP *ip;
}MACHINE; `

ADRESSIP is
`typedef struct adressIP{ // la structure AdressIP
    int n1;
    int n2;
    int n3;
    int n4;
}ADRESSIP; `

RESEAU is
`typedef struct reseau{ // la structure reseau comme une liste
    MACHINE *suivant;
    long long size;
    short vide;
}RESEAU; `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution. I don't know what's the use you will do of this code. I've added the instructions that you indicates in a separated way into the function `create_machine`. THE CODE HERE IS ONLY A SOLUTION TO SOLVE THE WARNING!

If you use the type `ADDRESSIP` into the structure `struct machine` you have to have already declared the `typedef {} ADDRESSIP;`

```
typedef struct adressIP { // la structure AdressIP
    int n1; int n2; int n3; int n4; }
ADRESSIP;

typedef struct machine{ // la structure Machine ,, represente un pc
    struct machine * suivant;
    const char nom;
    ADRESSIP *ip;
} MACHINE;

typedef struct reseau{ // la structure reseau comme une liste
    MACHINE * suivant;
    long long size;
    short vide; }
RESEAU;


MACHINE * create_machine(RESEAU *r){ // Creation d'une machine and erreur
    MACHINE *m = malloc(sizeof(MACHINE));
    if(m == NULL){
        printf("\nErreur");
        return NULL;
    }

    ADRESSIP * ip = malloc(sizeof(ADRESSIP));
    if(ip == NULL){
        printf("\nErreur");
        return NULL;
    }

    m->suivant = NULL;
    m->ip = ip; //erreur

    return m;
}
```